# Workday API - GET_PAYMENT_ELECTION_ENROLLMENTS

Tags: workday-api

We are using Informatica Intelligent Cloud Services (IICS) to connect to Workday (WD) and retrieve the information via API.

We are trying to get the bank details for a specific set of employees via the **Cash Management** ---> **GET_PAYMENT_ELECTION_ENROLLMENTS**

However there is no REQUEST CRITERIA available for this for us to filter on say Nationality or City.

Is it possible to have a API code with request criteria for this operation.

Thanks

Anand

Answer (score 0):

There's not currently Request Criteria, so you would need to build a Report and make a REST call.